# How to populate GridView from an API call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, gridview, webforms

I am a beginner learning ASP.NET and I am working on a project where I need to create a Web API to get data from an SQL Server and then call that API from a Web Form to populate a gridview table.

I've currently gotten the Web API to properly get the SQL table and 'send' it to `http://localhost:58749/api/Movie`

Here is the code for my Web API Model and Controller classes:

```
namespace MovieAPI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class tblMovie
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
        public string MovieRating { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MovieAPI.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MovieAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MovieController : ApiController
    {

        public IHttpActionResult getMovieDetails()
        {
            MoviesDBEntities entities = new MoviesDBEntities();
            var results = entities.tblMovies.ToList();
            return Ok(results);
        }

    }
}
```

When I press the play button in visual studio and then navigate to the appropriate URL, the output is something like this:

```
[{"MovieID":1,"MovieTitle":"From Dusk Til Dawn","MovieRating":"R    ","ReleaseYear":1996},{"MovieID":2,"MovieTitle":"Neighbors","MovieRating":"R    ","ReleaseYear":2014},{"MovieID":4,"MovieTitle":"Avengers: Infinity War","MovieRating":"PG-13","ReleaseYear":2018}]
```

The problem I am running into is how to actually call the web API using HttpClient. I'm using HttpClient because I believe it is what is called for in the project. My Web Form backend looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using MovieAPI.Models;

namespace MovieWebForm
{
    public partial class Movie : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58749/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Movie");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var movies = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<tblMovie>();
                    // add to datagrid
                    
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Web Form front end:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Movie.aspx.cs" Inherits="MovieWebForm.Movie" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
           <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="MovieID" DataField="MovieID"> </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="MovieRating" DataField="MovingRating"> </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="MovieTitle" DataField="MovieTitle"> </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="ReleaseYear" DataField="ReleaseYear"> </asp:BoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The HttpClient code I have there is from the documentation example. I've been unable to get any response however, although it's possible I'm checking the wrong place. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to properly call the Web API in a way that would populate the gridview with the table data. I think the gridview outline I have would work if I knew how to properly call the Web API.

Any tips or suggestions?

EDIT: I modified the HTTP GET to be more in line with examples I see online. Also, the project specified Datagrid, which I assumed to be Gridview but perhaps the two are different.

EDIT 2: Changed the output section as it should now output JSON instead of XML. Also inserted my current Web Form front end.

Comment: @Timonthy Shels First, you need to set the output data in JSON format properly and show your Datagrid Html page code.

Currently, you are sending the XML format data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json; 

  

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
          wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
          string URL = "http://localhost:58749/api/Movie";                         
          string result = wc.DownloadString(URL);
 //Deserializing the response recieved from  api and storing into the your object or list  
      var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(result);
        }
```